# Warning: `dart` dart.exe, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

From the last update i have been facing this problem when i run flutter doctor

The loge is given bellow:-

```
C:\Users\choyo>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3324], locale en-US)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to C:\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK
      checkout at C:\flutter. Consider adding C:\flutter\bin to the front of your path.
```

please help me to solve this problem

I want to resolve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Do what it says? Add `C:\flutter\bin` to path - https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=add+to+path+windows